# Youtube iFrame API act weird with modestbranding:1 and showinfo:0

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm trying to get clean Youtube player without the song title, "watch later" button, share button and Youtube logo.

Thefore, after read the [playerVars API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#Parameters), i'm setting this:

```
new YT.Player('someId', {
    width: 460,
    height: 390,
    playerVars: {
        modestbranding: 1,
        fs: false,
        showinfo: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        wmode: 'opaque',
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 1,
        html5: 1,
        enablejsapi: 1,
        rel: 0
});
```

I'm still getting the YouTube logo on the bottom right corner, see this:

[image]

If i'm remove the `showinfo: 0` the logo disappear but then the song title, the "watch later" and "share buttons appear on top:

[image]

Any suggestions how i can hide all at once?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with embedding a youtube video on a `cordova` mobile app.